# Preserve `$location.search()` in angular `redirectTo`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

How can I preserve `$location.search()` with

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: xxx})
```

I know, I can use a function there, which gets the old object `$location.search()` as the third argument. I mostly care about a single key, let's call it `a`, and I tried

```
function(a, b, search) {
    return "/mainpage?a=" + search[a];
}
```

but it always ends with `/mainpage?a=undefined`. What's worse, it crashes my debugger, which slows me down. Moreover, this doesn't work for all keys (which I may need later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a new approach, where you listen for `$routeChangeStart` and modify the `search()` if the previous (non-existing) page contained *important* GET parameters. Complete source and a demo can be found on [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pyzLvwx11gLArjkC1Fu0?p=preview).

The concept is similar to @Mikko's solution, but the implementation is a bit different (no custom provider) and it works as per author's instructions.

**The essence**

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'URL', function($rootScope, $location, URL) {

    // Previous search() value
    var prevSearch = {};

    // Listen to event
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, current) {

        // Have search() parameters and are going to default route
        if(prevSearch !== undefined && $location.path().endsWith(URL.defaultRoute)) {

            // Extract only important params
            var important = {};
            var importantCount = 0;

            for(var param in prevSearch) {

                if(URL.importantParams.indexOf(param) > -1) {

                    important[param] = prevSearch[param];
                    importantCount++;

                }

            }

            // Unset prevSearch
            prevSearch = {};

            // Apply important params, if any
            if(importantCount > 0) {

                $location.search(important);

            }


        } else {

            // Remember current search()
            prevSearch = $location.search();

        }

    });

}]);
```

The `run` function sets a listener for `$routeChangeStart` and also remembers previous values of the `search()` value (the GET params).

When the app is redirected to the default route, it checks for the previous value of the `search()` parameters and extracts only the important ones. If any, it overrides the `search()` value and therefore sets the important GET parameters to the default route.

I have made an `URL` constant in which one can set the default route and specify the important parameters. The code is the following:

```
angular.module('myApp').constant('URL', {
    defaultRoute: '/mainpage',
    importantParams: ['a', 'b'],
});
```

**The demo**

The *first* link contains 3 parameters on a non-existing URL. The page is correctly redirected to the default route and only the 2 important ones are preserved.

The *second* and *fourth* links doesn't contain any parameters and both links don't apply any additional parameters (regardless on which page you are when you click them).

The *third* link also contains 3 parameters on the default route and all of them are preserved (no redirecting takes place).

Comment: Nice to hear I have inspired someone :) ! Reusability aside, shouldn't navigating from `Default URL with params` to e.g. `Non-existing URL without params` still preserve the parameters? In otherwords, non existing url, with or without parameters, should always redirect to `main` using params from last known "good" route?

Comment: I accepted this answer as it's simpler and awarded the bounty to @MikkoViitala as he was first. +++ Concerning using params from last known "good" route, I actually don't care. The user comes from elsewhere using a link leading to `http://example.com?important=42` and I have to redirect them to `http://example.com/main?important=42`. A similar case would be `http://example.com/non-existing-page?important=42`. That's about all I need for now, haven't thought about more complicated cases yet. Thank to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, that in the configuration phase (`.config()` function), you can only inject providers. And since `$location` is not a provider, you cannot inject it. Therefore the `$location.search()` is not working.

You can, however, use the plain JavaScript's `window.location.hash` in order to obtain the URL parameters. But, this is not the *Angular way* and it does not work as you would wish.

For example, if you use the following configuration code:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    // Return $location.search() equivalent object
    function locationSearch() {

        var search = {};
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var index = hash.indexOf('?');

        // Has parameters
        if(index > -1) {

            // Extract only the params
            var params = hash.substring(index + 1);

            // Split parameters
            params = params.split('&');

            var tmp;
            for(var i = 0, len = params.length; i < len; i++) {

                tmp = params[i].split('=');
                search[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];

            }

        }

        return search;

    }

    // Generate default URL
    function defaultURL(search) {

        if(search.a === undefined) {

            return '/mainpage';

        } else {

            return '/mainpage?a=' + search.a;

        }

    }

    // Equivalent of $location.search()
    var search = locationSearch();

    // Set up routing
    $routeProvider

        // Events
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl'
        })

        // Default page
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: defaultURL(search)
        });

}]);
```

With the above code, you can access the equivalent of `$location.search()`, and compile a dynamic URL as a default route - **BUT** the ngRoute *escapes it*.

For example, the `defaultURL()` function produces something like this: `/mainpage?a=123`. However, the ngRoute escapes the special characters (i.e. `?` and `&`) and you get redirected to `/mainpage%3Fa=123`, which doesn't work as intended.

Further, this only works when you *freshly* open a page with that URL. When you are already on the page and change to a non-valid URL, the above code doesn't work since the configuration phase is already been done - the `.config()` fires only once per page load.

**TL;DR**

To my knowledge, this cannot be done by using the `$routeProvider.otherwise()` method inside the configuration phase.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `provider`, which you wire up during `config` and `run` phases, to preserve your search parameters.

Let's say you have the following:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .provider('myRoute', function myRouteProvider() {
    var defaultUrl;
    var search;

    // get default url with params (config phase)
    this.default = function() {
      var params = '';
      angular.forEach(search, function(value, key) {
        params = params + key + '=' + value + '&';
      });

      if (params.length > 0) {
        params = params.substring(0, params.length - 1);
      }

      var redirectUrl = defaultUrl + (params ? '?' + params : '');
      console.log(redirectUrl);
      return redirectUrl;
    };

    this.$get = function($rootScope) {
      var myRoute = {};

      // set default url (run phase)
      myRoute.setDefault = function(url) {
        if (defaultUrl) {
          throw 'Provider already initialized';
        }

        defaultUrl = url;

        // update params on route change
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
          search = current.params;
        });
      };

      return myRoute;      
    };
  }) 

  .config(function($routeProvider, myRouteProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      })
      .when('/route1', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      })
      .when('/route2', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        // redirect to default url with latest params
        redirectTo: myRouteProvider.default
      });
  })

  .run(function(myRoute) {
    // set default url (404)
    myRoute.setDefault('/main');
  })

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;
  });
```

Where `index.html` contains just

```
<div>
  <a href="#/main">main</a><br>
  <a href="#/route1">route1</a><br>
  <a href="#/route2?param=abc">route2?param=abc</a><br>
  <a href="#/404">otherwise</a><br>
</div>
<hr>
<div ng-view></div>
```

and routes' `template.html` is simply

```
<div>
  path: {{ $location.path() }}
  <br>
  params: {{ $location.search() }}
</div>
```

Now if you navigate between links and hit `othwerwise`, you'll be redirected to `/main` with any `params` from previous route.

[image: imgur]

---

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/cqR2Nh

Comment: I accepted the other answer as it's simpler and awarded the bounty to you as you were first. To me that fact that it's necessary to do such things looks like an angular bug.